# HTML input field already filled out with information from another site

Tags: html, forms, input

I've added two input fields to my site, one for the username and one for the password to log in to.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</form>
```

However, the two fields are already filled out with information I use to log in to a *completely different website*. How can I make sure that this doesn't happen to other users?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/w7hiZgv.png]

Comment: What browser are you using?  Most browsers match credentials to the main URL (i.e. the part between http:// and the next /.  You can prevent anything from ever being in there by using some javascript after the page is loaded to clear out all input fields...  but that's not very nice.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Firefox v35

Answer (score 0):

If your not using chrome, value="" should work.

```
input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

You need to do the same for password and username.